# Edit Text value not getting changed- Android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

So, what I want to do is, if name or contact field is empty, the want to print the message, else submit.
Now, the problem is, for the first trial(Both field empty), it's giving me 'Enter the name'. Then even if I enter name again, still the same.

Can you please help me..

Here is the code...

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    final EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    final String cust_name=name.getText().toString();
    final String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();


sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
            if(cust_name.length()==0)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name must be      provided!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else if(phone_num.length()==0)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must provide your phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
            {   
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the `getText()` code lines in the `onclicklistener` of the button.

It's not working because you are getting text from the edittexts in the onCreate(). `onCreate()` is  a callback which is called by the system when the activity starts. By the time it starts the edittexts don't contain any values. But only after you entered some values in the edittexts, then only you can get the values when you click the button. So, the `getText()` code lines should be moved into `onClick()` which is always called when you click on button.

```
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) { 

 String cust_name=name.getText().toString();
     String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();

            if(cust_name.length()==0)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name must be      provided!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else if(phone_num.length()==0)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must provide your phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
            {   
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here in below lines of code

```
oncreate(--) {
 ---
 --- 
   final String cust_name=name.getText().toString(); // here edittexts are empty hence string variables are empty too.
    final String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();

}
```

You are setting cust_name and phone_num in oncreate() method , hence they are empty always, no matter what you type later on.. your code must be something like below

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final Button sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
            final EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final EditText phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);




        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                       String cust_name=name.getText().toString();
                    String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();
                    if(cust_name.length()==0)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name must be      provided!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    else if(phone_num.length()==0)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must provide your phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    else
                    {   
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    }
                }  
        });
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the problems?

Answer (score 0):

move `name.getText().toString()` and `phone. getText(). toString()` inside button click to get latest value from it as :

```
String cust_name,phone_num;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      // your code here
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
       cust_name=name.getText().toString();
       phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();
       //..your code here
```

Comment: @bookishq : it's good if you declare all elements before onCreate and initilze it inside on Create after setContentView by this  you can able to access all elements in other methods

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {  

           final String cust_name=name.getText().toString();
           final String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();

            if(cust_name.length()==0)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name must be      provided!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else if(phone_num.length()==0)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must provide your phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
            {   
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make it a nested type condtion and then check it will work fine

```
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {  
            if(cust_name.equals(""))
              {
                if(phone_num.equals(""))
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must provide your phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name must be      provided!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}    


            else
            {   
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare edittext variable public so you can used anywhere in this class.

```
String cust_name,phone_num;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//your code for intialize another variable  
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) { 
    if(cust_name.getText().toString().length()==0){
        //toast with error message
    }else if(phone_num.getText().toString().length()==0){
        //toast with error message
    }else{
        //you have to get fresh value           

    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code you have shared, your name and phone number strings will always remain empty. Hence, no matter what you add to the EditText box, they will never be populated in the String thus throwing you the same error again and again.

The following should work.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    final EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText phone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //final String cust_name=name.getText().toString(); **REMOVE**
    //final String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString(); **REMOVE**


sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
            String cust_name=name.getText().toString();
            String phone_num=phone. getText(). toString();  
            if(cust_name.length()==0)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name must be      provided!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else if(phone_num.length()==0)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must provide your phone number!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else
            {   
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
        }  
});
```

This time, when you press the submit button, we will get the text which is in the EditText box at **THAT** moment. Hence, it will not be empty if you enter something through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `[TextViewName].getText().length()==0` instead of `[TextViewName].getText()==0`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are getting text from the edittexts in the onCreate(). onCreate()  is called by the system when the activity starts. At that time the edittexts don't contain any values. But only after you entered some values in the edittexts, then only you can get the values when you click the button.

move

> name.getText().toString()

and

> phone. getText(). toString()

inside button click to get latest value from it as.